# random ng-show within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-show

I can't see to figure this out... I'm new to angular so sorry if I'm doing something stupid.

I want to show parts of the directive randomly using ng-show.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="color in colors">
        <my-directive color="color"></my-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.colors = [
        {color: "red", stuff: "1"},
        {color: "blue", stuff: "2"},
        {color: "yellow", stuff: "3"}
    ];
}
```

directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            color: '=',
            showText: '@'
        },
        template: 'test <p ng-show="showText">{{color.color}} {{color.stuff}}</p>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.showText = Math.random() < 0.5;
        }
    }
});
```

The `<p>...</p>` never shows, why?

http://jsfiddle.net/oxr4c9ub/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have a (`@`) text binding on the scope property `showText`. When the directive renders it evaluates the controller and sets the property value on the isolated scope object, but it afterwards evaluates the text binding and overwrites the scope property `showText` even if there is no value bound to it. So basically the random boolean you set is being overwritten by the `@` bound property (undefined/null), which being falsy will always hide the `p` tag.

You could just remove `showText: '@'` from the directive setting, if you do not need it or defer the setting of property value to the next digest cycle possibly by using a `$timeout`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rv9y05xz/)**

Comment: @BhojendraSah I believe `showText` is being bound so that the directive can be controlled by the consumer, so i will still leave it there and place a check for the presence of value before applying my random. :)